# Grammar of relative clause appositives missing relativizer

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In noun phrases like

1. **The man I asked** said that ...

I think *I asked* is a relative clause? How can the noun phrase be syntactically analysed? What is the name of the phenomena of omitting the *that*/*who* relativizer, and is it correct to call *I asked* an appositive?

Comment: The relative pronoun (_that, which, who_) may be deleted in relative clauses, **provided** it is not the subject of the verb in the relative clause. _The man I asked_ is short for _the man that/who I asked_, and there the relative pronoun is the direct object of _ask_, not its subject.  So it may be deleted, and here it has been. Oh, and they're not appositives, they're just relative clauses.

Comment: Yes, "I asked" is a relative clause. More specifically, the omission of the subordinator "that" marks it as a **bare relative**. The covert relativised element is object of "asked": "The man [(that) I asked ___ ] said that ... ".

Comment: Compare *the man whom I asked* and *the man who answered*. *Whom* is the object of *asked*, while *who* is the subject of *answered*. You can omit the relative pronoun that serves as an object.

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler wrote in a comment:

> The relative pronoun (*that, which, who*) may be deleted in relative clauses, **provided** it is not the subject of the verb in the relative clause. *The man I asked* is short for *the man that/who I asked*, and there the relative pronoun is the direct object of *ask*, not its subject.  So it may be deleted, and here it has been. Oh, and they're not appositives, they're just relative clauses.